# Using file system passthrough with KVM guests

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

With a 16.04 hypervisor and 16.04 guest I would like direct access to my host filesystem from my guests.  I have created the following element inside the  section:

```
<filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
  <source dir='/mnt/gsystem/fs'/>
  <target dir='/mnt/fs'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</filesystem>
```

After rebooting the guest, the PCI device at slot #3 shows up and I can see it as follows (I have edited out other PCI devices for clarity):

```
# lspci
...
00:03.0 Unclassified device [0002]: Red Hat, Inc Virtio filesystem
...
```

But the file system isn't mounted and the target directory stays local to the guest.

Is there a next step to take or is thee a driver in my VM that I am missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You syntax is mostly used for LXC guest, KVM is a bit different. Update your XML like bellow:

```
<filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
 <source dir='/mnt/gsystem/fs'/>
 <target dir='mymount'/>
</filesystem>
```

Start you guest and manually add modules to guest boot.

```
cat >>/etc/modules <<EOF
loop
virtio
9p
9pnet
9pnet_virtio
EOF
```

Manually insert all those modules with

```
service kmod start
```

And finally try to mount the shared folder

```
mount mymount /mnt/fs -t 9p -o trans=virtio
```

If it's working, umount and add the following line into your `/etc/fstab` to make the mount persistant.

```
 mymount /mnt/fs            9p             trans=virtio    0       0
```

Finally try to mount it again with

```
mount -a
```

Sources : http://rabexc.org/posts/p9-setup-in-libvirt

Comment: This works but the usage of the "target" parameter ("fs" in this case) doesn't seem to be a path name.   Other than that I am having difficulty getting write access to the file system from the guest.   I'll read the link to see if I can solve that myself.

Comment: the target is a simple label in that case, just choose any name that you want. For the write access, this is mostly a permission issue on the host, more info on the link provided.

Comment: I've spent 20 minutes trying to get this answer to work on at least 4 separate occasions. The issue every time was selinux. This method does not work with selinux=enabled or permissive. After disabling selinux these steps worked like a charm.

Comment: Modern hosts and guests likely want to use `virtiofs` instead of the old `9p` stuff. https://libvirt.org/kbase/virtiofs.html

Answer (score 4):

Using virt-manager and Ubuntu 22.04 as the guest this works out of the box.

First in the VM's Memory configuration check "Enable shared memory".

Next in virt-manager add a new Filesystem with:

- `driver` set to virtiofs
- `source path` set to the host's directory to share
- `target path` set to any string e.g. `myshare` (this isn't actually a path but some kind of reference label, used below).

Start the guest and from there create a mount point like `/media/share`, and finally run `sudo mount -t virtiofs myshare /media/share`

To add this to `/etc/fstab` it should look like:

```
myshare /media/share virtiofs rw,noatime,_netdev 0 2
```